# Get reminders on specific dates (via e-mail or XMPP) from a free/libre tool running on my own server

Tags: linux, open-source, web-apps, reminders, self-hosted

I want to get reminders on specific dates.

The web app must be FLOSS and I want to self-host it on my own server (GNU/Linux).

Features:

- **Adding a reminder** should be hassle-free and quick. Ideally it only shows a date and a title/description field.
- Each reminder must be sent either via SMTP (e-mail) or via XMPP (Jabber). One **message** per reminder.
- Each message should contain a **confirmation link**. Unless I visit this specific URL, the reminder should be sent again (in configurable intervals).

I don’t necessarily look for a full calendar application; in fact, I’d prefer a smaller, specialized tool. But if a calendar fulfils all requirements, it’s certainly acceptable.

Comment: How about your own machine? Thunderbird can do this.

Comment: @Nemo: This would only help when I’m sitting at this machine, but I primarily need this solution in situations where I’m not.